# Can not browse to previously authenticated page

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to asp.net core and I have problem with my website. 
I have searched more and more but in vain.

My application is using asp.net core 2.* and consists of two areas: Admin and User

I created a login page for each area and the authentication in startup.cs file code is below.

The application is running successfully but my problem is that when browsing to an authenticated page then clicking back in the browser,
the website will go to the login page. When I reload this page the website will load the authenticated page (the required page that I want to return by back button).

This means that (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticted` variable is false when browser go to previous page) but when browser make new request again to this page then this variable will equal to true and render properly page.

I understand the problem but I cannot solve this problem. Please can anyone help me and save my time?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        string UserScheme = "UserScheme";
        services.AddDbContext<FastDoEntities>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FastDoEntities")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FastDoEntities")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthorization(autorizationOptions =>
        {
            autorizationOptions.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(UserScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole("User");

            }).
             autorizationOptions.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AdminScheme);
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                policy.RequireRole("Admin");

            });
        });
        services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddCookie("UserScheme", CookieBuilder =>
        {
            CookieBuilder.Cookie.Path = "/";
            CookieBuilder.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
            CookieBuilder.AccessDeniedPath = "/User/AccessDenied";
            CookieBuilder.Cookie.Name = "UserCookie";
        })
       .AddCookie("AdminScheme", CookieBuilder =>
        {
            CookieBuilder.Cookie.Path = "/";
            CookieBuilder.LoginPath = "/Admin/Login";
            CookieBuilder.AccessDeniedPath = "/Admin/AccessDenied";
            CookieBuilder.Cookie.Name = "AdminCookie";
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you paste the `Configure` function? did you add the `UseAuthentication` in it

Comment: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();
           
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                 
        }
    }

Comment: yes,i used the UseAuthebtication(),and my authentication is working properly but problem is that authentication not working when user back to previous page

Comment: after clicking the back button did you try a refresh? The back button would show the previous page not the latest version of it

Comment: yes ,when i try to refresh, the authenticated page is rendered properly